# create trigger to check user activities on table in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have already asked a similar question here and it is about creating a trigger to capture user activity on a specific table.

This should make an entry in another table depending on the values of a column from this table.
The problem is that the trigger is fired as soon as it finds the value of the column.
However, I want to bind this entry, which means the trigger should be fired when the value of the column matches  and only for the respective user.

This is what I get:
[image]
This is what I actually want:
[image]

but the problem is I'm not sure how to bind it to the Tbl1 ID, because it doesn't exist in the beginning.

```
   create or replace TRIGGER TRG_AUDIT_TBL1
      -- starts on every update or insert command
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
      FOR EACH ROW
    
DECLARE
      v_user varchar2(30);
      v_done_action varchar2(50);
         
    BEGIN
       v_user := SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER');
        
       IF :NEW.STATE ='REQUESTED'  then
        v_done_action :='text32154';
         INSERT INTO table2
        (tblid,tbl1column1, DONE_ACTION)
       VALUES
        (:NEW.tblid, :NEW.column1, v_done_action);        
      
        ELSIF :NEW.STATE ='APPROVED'  THEN
        v_done_action :='text321.';
        INSERT INTO table2
        (tblid,tbl1column1, DONE_ACTION)
       VALUES
        (:NEW.tblid, :NEW.column1, v_done_action); 
    end if
    end;
```

Comment: Both the desired and actual results have `done_action` of `text123` in `table2`.  Your code has no code path that inserts that value.  I don't understand what you mean by "bind this entry".  It will probably be necessary to provide us with the `insert` and `update` statements that produce the data in `table1` and explain for which statements the trigger is supposed to write values to `table2`.

Comment: the trigger should make an entry in table 2 when the value of the State column in table 1 changes. however, the trigger now checks the value of this column for each row in table 1 and makes an entry in table 2.

Comment: My guess would be that you want your `if` statements to include conditions on `:old.state` as well.  But that's a guess since I don't know what your application is doing to produce the data in `table1`.  In your most recent edit, you fixed the `done_action` issue but the desired and actual state of `table2` now appear to be identical which is, presumably, not correct.

Comment: in order to produce the data in table 1 the user has to submit a form in the frontend in which he enters his data. And yes you were right about the desired and actual state of table 2:) I edited it again

Comment: Since we don't have access to your application or know what the front-end's form is doing, we don't know how the data in `table1` comes to exist in the state that it's in.  That makes it very hard for us to guess at what you actually want your trigger to do.  If you're going to debug the trigger, you'll want to include `insert` and `update` statements on `table1` that simulate what the front-end is doing.  If you include that and explain which statements you want to cause the trigger to write a row to `table2` we can probably help.

Comment: Beyond just saying that it sounds like you probably want your trigger to include conditions on `:old.state`.  I'd personally expect that you'd be better off putting the inserts into `table2` into your APEX application or the procedures that application calls since that likely gives you more context about what is changing.